# How to install LLVM 3.7.x on Ubuntu 14.01 (llvm.org/apt down)

Tags: 14.04, apt, python, compiling

I am trying to install LLVM 3.7.x in order to get `llvmlite` for Python 2.7. However, the apt mirror seems to be down, reading:

> APT mirror was temporary switched off due to excess load. We are working on bringing it back. Stay tuned!

I was wondering how I can build llvm from source on Ubuntu 14.01. I am a Linux novice.

Comment: It might be easier to just wait, though...

Comment: Hmm... I think the website has been down for several days, perhaps several weeks

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as one. Also, why `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`? It's your `.bashrc`, there's no need for `sudo`.

Comment: Hmm... I thought you needed sudo permissions to edit and save hidden files. It seems to work without  sudo though. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to build LLVM 3.7.1 using the following steps. I am not sure if this is the 'proper' way to do it, but hopefully others can correct me if any of the steps are wrong. This was largely based on http://linuxdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/06/building-llvm-342-from-source.html

```
mkdir llvm
cd llvm
wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.1/llvm-3.7.1.src.tar.xz
wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.1/cfe-3.7.1.src.tar.xz
wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.1/compiler-rt-3.7.1.src.tar.xz

tar xf ./llvm-3.7.1.src.tar.xz
tar xf ./cfe-3.7.1.src.tar.xz
tar xf ./compiler-rt-3.7.1.src.tar.xz

mv ./llvm-3.7.1.src ./llvm-3.7.1
mv ./cfe-3.7.1.src ./clang
mv ./clang ./llvm-3.7.1/tools/
mv ./compiler-rt-3.7.1 ./compiler-rt
mv ./compiler-rt ./llvm-3.7.1/projects/

mkdir ./build
cd ./build
../llvm-3.7.1/configure --enable-shared --enable-targets=host-only
../llvm-3.7.1/configure –help

time make -j 3
make check-all

gedit ~/.bashrc
#(add  export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/llvm/build/Release+Asserts/bin and close)
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/llvm.conf
#/home/<my user name>/llvm/build/Release+Asserts/lib

make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks AstronomyGeek !
However, some typos in the script:

```
mv ./compiler-rt-3.7.1.src ./compiler-rt
mv ./compiler-rt ./llvm-3.7.1/projects/'
```

and unnecessary to have `../llvm-3.7.1/configure –help`